# Subtype entities can not be found from cache

Tags: breeze

I have a data structure like:

```
public abstract class Vehicle { }
public class Car : Vehicle { }
public class MotorCycle : Vehicle { }
```

which works very well with breezejs, but when i want to get the entities from the cache:

```
function getLocal() {
    var entity = manager.getEntityByKey("Vehicle", id);   
}
```

with "Vehicle" (base class) as the resource parameter, the entity can not be found, whereas "Car" or "MotorCycle" works.

I've found out, that in the getEntityByKey function (breezejs/EntityManager.js)

```
proto.getEntityByKey = function () {
    var entityKey = createEntityKey(this, arguments).entityKey;
    var group;
    var subtypes = entityKey._subTypes;
    if (subtypes) {
        for (var i = 0, j = subtypes.length; i < j; i++) {
            group = this._findEntityGroup(subtypes[i]);
            // group version of findEntityByKey doesn't care about entityType
            var ek = group && group.findEntityByKey(entityKey);
            if (ek) return ek;
        }
    } else {
        group = this._findEntityGroup(entityKey.entityType);
        return group && group.findEntityByKey(entityKey);
    }
};
```

Line:

```
var subtypes = entityKey._subTypes;
```

_subTypes are written in camelCase and are ever undefined because the property is defined as _subtypes (lowerCase).
If i change to _subtypes, the function works perfectly as expected.

Is this a bug or did i missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug. We fix this in the next release. ... and thanks for finding it. :)